# How to access particular element of tuples which are inside a nested dictionary Python

Tags: python

```
database={'PC2': 
['02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2', '200', 
{'192.168.0.2': ('02:02:02:02:02:02', 1390555956.276)}], 
'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200', 
{'192.168.0.2': ('02:02:02:02:02:02', 1390555956.276), 
'192.168.0.1': ('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390555945.453)}]}
```

Please note that database[j][3] is the location of cache table of a particular host(it is inside the main dictinary"database")

```
k = "Enter <host_id>"
j = raw_input(k)
if j in database and database!={}:
    print database[j][3]
```

Above is what I am trying forexample i input PC1 I am getiing following output:

```
{'192.168.0.2': ('02:02:02:02:02:02', 1390555956.276),
'192.168.0.1': ('01:01:01:01:01:01', 1390555945.453)}
```

But I want output like this:

```
02:02:02:02:02:02      192.168.0.2
01:01:01:01:01:01      192.168.0.1
```

(After printing each MAC(1st element of every tuple e.g.02:02:02:02:02:02) and IP present inside cache table it should go on next line also and then print the next MAC and IP present in the same cache table of same PC).

Kindly help.

Comment: As a side note, you're overcomplicating things for no reason. First, if `j in database` is true, then obviously `database!={}` must be true, so why check it? (And even if you do need to check it, as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says, just use `database`, not `database!={}` or `len(database)>1` or anything else; an empty collection is falsey, a non-empty collection is truthy.) But really, you rarely need to "pre-check" like this at all; either write your code to use non-failing methods like `.get` instead of `[]`, or use `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Python 2:

```
>>> for ip, (mac, t) in database['PC1'][3].items(): print mac, ip
02:02:02:02:02:02 192.168.0.2
01:01:01:01:01:01 192.168.0.1
```

For Python 3, we need to add parentheses:

```
>>> for ip, (mac, t) in database['PC1'][3].items(): print(mac, ip)
02:02:02:02:02:02 192.168.0.2
01:01:01:01:01:01 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: I am getting following output with what you suggested:                ('02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2')
('01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1')

Comment: I just want to print in string format not tuple format like this

Comment: @user3209413 Does the update solve that issue for you?

Comment: You could also just do, e.g., `print('{} {}'.format(mac, ip))`, which works the same in 2.x and 3.x, and shows explicitly what this is supposed to look like instead of making you infer it from the commas, and makes it easy to, e.g., add labels, or customize the widths, or change the separators, etc.

Comment: @John1024 I am using python 2.7 but not getting the output like you have mentioned instead I am getting a tuple  i.e.('02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2') then new line and ('01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1')

Comment: @user3209413 In that case, please try it again using the Python 2 solution shown above, which has `print max, ip` rather than the Python 3 solution which has `print(max,ip)`.